# None Type from cv2 into PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, opencv

I'm writing a program that captures the stream from the ip camera using cv2, looks for faces in the frame and sends the image to PyQt5, the camera can pass the None Type attribute, in general it would not be a problem, but I compile the program via pyinstller, and when I can not grab frame, the application is completely closed, how can this be avoided ??

Comment: have you tried using sockets

Comment: I'm newbie to programming, could not give a short example on python, how can this be done?

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).